# Selenium identify tag

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Any ideas how to identify the "reservation.date" in the tag below, in order to extract the date which is 28/07/2018 using Python Selenium? Thanks!

```
<td align="center" abbr="reservation.date"><div>Sat<br>28/07/2018 12:00</div> 
</td>
```

Comment: @jxw Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Your code trials?

Comment: I am using Python. I have tried to identify the element with tag name, however, it was too unspecific. I am very new to selenium but I will try to read up on how to use css selector.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this **xpath** :

```
//td[@abbr='reservation.date']/descendant::br
```

**Python code :**

```
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@abbr='reservation.date']/descendant::br")  
print(date.text)
```

**Css selector** would be :

```
td[abbr='reservation.date'] br
```

**Python code** :

```
date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[abbr='reservation.date'] br')
print(date.text)
```

I am not sure whether you want to introduce **WebDriverWait**.

**Update :**

```
div<class ="stackover" id="stack" , arial-view="foo">
```

**Css would be :**

```
div.stackover
```

or

```
div#stack
```

or

```
div[arial-view='foo']
```

Comment: There is no text inside the `BR` tag. These locators won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply cruisepandey it really helped! As JeffC pointed out, the locator did not work, so I ended with this line of code instead date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td[abbr='reservation.date']"). Is there anywhere I can read more about identifying tag with css selector? More specifically, I am not sure what [] in the syntax means.

Comment: `div<class ="stackover" id="stack" , arial-view="foo">` , for this , if you want to write css selector : 1. `div.stackover` or 2. `div#stack` or `div[arial-view='foo']` , all will work.

Comment: explanation : This is how we write css selector : `tagname[attributeName = 'attribute value']` , you can refer this link :https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @JeffC:  yeah I did not notice , those are text nodes , you can easily retrieve those using Javascript. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: You should really update your answer now since it was accepted. Someone will come along later and think this is supposed to work if they don't read the comments first.